# How to format this date so it's more readable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have date in this format:

`2022-06-28T17:09:00.922108+01:00`

I want to covert it into a more readable format.
I'm using javascript/react and I tried moment-js but it gives me "invalid format".

What are my other options of turning it into a normal date?

Comment: What do you mean a "normal date"? That is a normal date, just in ISO format. What format do you want it in? Where does this date come from (ie, is it a javascript date object, or is it a string)?

Comment: I want to display it as Year, Day, Month, Hour, Minute, Second

Comment: @Jamiec hey - knowing that it's an ISO type helped me figure out how to handle it.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to format date:

```
const format = "DD-MM-YYYY"
moment(date).format(format)
```

or

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // June 28th 2022, 9:49:49 pm
```

for more detail refer: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using moment.js you can convert this to any format you like using this [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Sample code

```
moment('2022-06-28T17:09:00.922108+01:00').format("DD-MM-YYYY"); //28-06-2022
```

Kindly go though the moment.js features and documents. There is a lot more you can do with this like showing time, day of the week etc

Comment: I did try it that way, but it kept returning my local time..  or it would return "invalid time".. but thank you - i will give it a try again

Comment: Just remove '+01:00' from the string

moment('2022-06-28T17:09:00'.split('+')[0]).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");  //'28-06-2022 17:09:00'

Comment: OR You could also specify the timezone using 
moment.tz('2022-06-28T17:09:30.922108+01:00', "Australia/Sydney").format("DD-MM-YYYY, h:mm:ss a");